# Duplicating a Hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm trying to initialize a Hash in ruby, by using another hash with default values. I want a deep copy but I only ever seem to get a shallow copy.

Here is an example:

```
DEFAULT_HASH = { a: 0, b: 1 }.freeze
my_hash = DEFAULT_HASH.dup
my_hash[:a] = 4
```

Now the value of a in "my_hash" and in DEFAULT_HASH is 4. I only want the value in my hash to change.

I have tried other approaches too:

```
my_hash = {}.merge DEFAULT_HASH
```

and

```
my_hash.merge! DEFAULT_HASH
```

All of these produce the same effect. What is the best way to achieve this sort of initialization. I'm also working with nested hashes which adds to the complexity a bit.

i.e. my DEFAULT_HASH looks like:

```
DEFAULT_HASH = { a:{a:1, b:2}, b:{a:2, b:1} }
```

Would this affect how to do this?

EDIT:
Nested Hash case

```
DEFAULT_HASH = { a:{a:1, b:2}, b:{a:2, b:1} }
=> {:a=>{:a=>1, :b=>2}, :b=>{:a=>2, :b=>1}} 
a=DEFAULT_HASH.dup
=> {:a=>{:a=>1, :b=>2}, :b=>{:a=>2, :b=>1}} 
a[:b][:a]=12
=> 12 
DEFAULT_HASH
=> {:a=>{:a=>1, :b=>2}, :b=>{:a=>12, :b=>1}}
```

Comment: What version of Ruby are you doing this with?  I can't reproduce your behavior.

Comment: This is with JRuby 1.7.19 and Ruby 2.2.0

Comment: I'm using a similar version of Ruby and I do not see the same thing.  Are you *certain* that `DEFAULT_HASH` is changing?

Comment: Positive, look at the edit I made to the question. That is the direct output from my irb session. You can see DEFAULT_HASH[:b][;a] gets the value 12

Comment: Okay, so I hadn't tested this with your *nested* case; this obviously changes things.  On a shallow hash, I don't see this behavior.

Comment: So the first example is fake?

Comment: Nope not fake, I see it if I include the .freeze part. Without that it works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To @pjs's point, `Hash#dup` will 'do the right thing' for the top level of a hash. For nested hashes however, it still fails.

If you're open to using a gem, consider using [deep_enumerable](https://github.com/dgopstein/deep_enumerable), a gem I wrote for exactly this purpose (among others).

```
DEFAULT_HASH = { a:{a:1, b:2}, b:{a:2, b:1} }
dupped = DEFAULT_HASH.dup

dupped[:a][:a] = 'updated'

puts "dupped:       #{dupped.inspect}"
puts "DEFAULT_HASH: #{DEFAULT_HASH.inspect}"


require 'deep_enumerable'
DEFAULT_HASH = { a:{a:1, b:2}, b:{a:2, b:1} }

deep_dupped = DEFAULT_HASH.deep_dup
deep_dupped[:a][:a] = 'updated'

puts "deep_dupped:  #{deep_dupped.inspect}"
puts "DEFAULT_HASH: #{DEFAULT_HASH.inspect}"
```

Output:

```
dupped:       {:a=>{:a=>"updated", :b=>2}, :b=>{:a=>2, :b=>1}}
DEFAULT_HASH: {:a=>{:a=>"updated", :b=>2}, :b=>{:a=>2, :b=>1}}

deep_dupped:  {:a=>{:a=>"updated", :b=>2}, :b=>{:a=>2, :b=>1}}
DEFAULT_HASH: {:a=>{:a=>1, :b=>2}, :b=>{:a=>2, :b=>1}}
```

Alternatively, you could try something along the lines of:

```
def deep_dup(h)
  Hash[h.map{|k, v| [k,
    if v.is_a?(Hash)
      deep_dup(v)
    else
      v.dup rescue v
    end
  ]}]
end
```

Note, this last function is nowhere near as well tested as `deep_enumerable`.

Comment: Perfect, I don't mind using a gem for this. It is quite an important part of my project.

Comment: very cool gem! I like the wider application to a bunch of other common depth problems

Answer (score 3):

You can easily create your own deep dup method, using [Marshal::dump](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Marshal.html#method-c-dump) and [Marshal::load](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Marshal.html#method-c-load):

```
def deep_dup(obj)
  Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(obj))
end
```

`obj` can be most any Ruby object (e.g., nested mix of arrays and hashes).

```
h = { a: { b: { c: { d: 4 } } } }

g = deep_dup(h)         #=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>{:d=>4}}}}

g[:a][:b][:c][:d] = 44  #=> 44
g                       #=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>{:d=>44}}}} 
h                       #=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>{:d=>4}}}}
```

For your example:

```
DEFAULT_HASH = { a: { a:1, b:2 }, b: { a:2, b:1 } }
  #=> {:a=>{:a=>1, :b=>2}, :b=>{:a=>2, :b=>1}} 
h = deep_dup(DEFAULT_HASH)
  #=> {:a=>{:a=>1, :b=>2}, :b=>{:a=>2, :b=>1}} 
h[:b][:a] = 12
  #=> 12
h #=> {:a=>{:a=>1, :b=>2}, :b=>{:a=>12, :b=>1}}
DEFAULT_HASH
  #=> {:a=>{:a=>1, :b=>2}, :b=>{:a=>2, :b=>1}}
```

Comment: While this is concise, I'm a little concerned in general about using functions like marshal and eval that are potentially vulnerable to injection attacks

Answer (score 0):

I added these to Array and Hash:

#Array

```
  def deep_dup
    result = []
    self.each do |v|
      if v.respond_to?(:deep_dup)
        result << v.deep_dup
      else
        result << v
      end
    end
    result
  end
```

#Hash

```
  def deep_dup
    result = {}
    self.each do |k,v|
      if v.respond_to?(:deep_dup)
        result[k] = v.deep_dup
      else
        result[k] = v
      end
    end
    result
  end
```

Answer (score -1):

Not `.freeze`ing gave the following result:

```
irb(main):001:0> DEFAULT_HASH = { a: 0, b: 1 }
=> {:a=>0, :b=>1}
irb(main):002:0> my_hash = DEFAULT_HASH.dup
=> {:a=>0, :b=>1}
irb(main):003:0> my_hash[:a] = 4
=> 4
irb(main):004:0> my_hash
=> {:a=>4, :b=>1}
irb(main):005:0> DEFAULT_HASH
=> {:a=>0, :b=>1}
```